# IfNoValueOrEmptyTF in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, xparse

In the following MWE, I would like to remove the space associated with the title, when the argument `##1` is mentioned but the title is empty. This would mean changing `IfValueTF` to `IfNoValueOrEmptyTF` in the `tcolorbox` declaration.

Is it possible to do this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\RequirePackage{scrhack}
\RequirePackage{luacode,luatextra}
\RequirePackage[fleqn]{mathtools,stmaryrd}
\RequirePackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
\RequirePackage{pdflscape}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
%
\RequirePackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{ et~}
\newcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{ et~}
\newcommand{\crefmiddleconjunction}{, }
\RequirePackage{totcount}
%
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF}{mmm}
    {
     \IfNoValueTF{#1}
      {#2} % true
      {\tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} {#2} {#3}} % false
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%
\RequirePackage{xargs}
\RequirePackage{centernot,cancel}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox,refcount}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table,x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{monbleu}{HTML}{003366}
%
%Encadrement
\RequirePackage[skins,breakable,xparse,many]{tcolorbox}
%--------------
%Définition/Théorème/etc.
%
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tcolorbox}{\savenotes}
\AfterEndEnvironment{tcolorbox}{\spewnotes}
%
\newcommand*\ifcounter[1]{%
  \ifcsname c@#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
%
\NewDocumentCommand\DefinirTheoreme{m m m m m m}{%
    \DeclareTColorBox[auto counter,
        number within       = chapter,
        crefname            = {#5}{#6}]{#1}{ o o }{
        enhanced ,
        coltitle            = #3    ,
        colframe            = #4    ,
        colbacktitle        = white ,
        boxrule             = 0.5pt ,
        toprule at break    = 0mm   ,
        bottomrule at break = 0mm   ,
        breakable                   ,
        attach boxed title to top left={xshift=3mm, yshift=-3mm, yshifttext=-1mm},
        IfValueTF={##1}{title=#2 \thetcbcounter {~|~} {\color{black}\normalfont\bfseries ##1}}{title=#2 \thetcbcounter},
        IfValueTF={##2}{##2}{},
        }
   }%
\DefinirTheoreme{defi}{Définition}{monbleu}{monbleu}{Définition}{Définitions}

%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{defi}[][label={croiss}]
Soit \((x,y)\in \left(\mathbb{R}_+\right)^2\) tel que \(x<y\) (resp. \(x\leqslant y)\), alors 
\[ x^2 < y^2 \;\; (\text{resp. }x^2 \leqslant y^2 ),  \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{y}.\]
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}
Soit \((x,y)\in \left(\mathbb{R}_+\right)^2\) tel que \(x<y\) (resp. \(x\leqslant y)\), alors 
\[ x^2 < y^2 \;\; (\text{resp. }x^2 \leqslant y^2 ),  \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{y}.\]
\end{defi}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't elaborate now (writing with a smartphone), but you probably want to use `O{}` instead of `o` as the argument specifier, and `\tl_if_blank:nTF`. Besides, the `\Declare...` is risky as it overwrites by design existing stuff with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes I made:

- Change the third argument of `\DeclareTColorBox` from `{ o o }` to `{ O{} O{} }`.
- In the forth argument of `\DeclareTColorBox`, change

  ```tex
  IfValueTF={##1}{title=#2 \thetcbcounter {~|~} {\color{black}\normalfont\bfseries ##1}}{title=#2 \thetcbcounter},
  IfValueTF={##2}{##2}{},
  ```

  to

  ```tex
  IfEmptyTF={##1}%
     {title=#2 \thetcbcounter}%
     {title=#2 \thetcbcounter {~|~}{\color{black}\normalfont\bfseries ##1}},
  ##2
  ```

Full example:

```tex
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\RequirePackage{scrhack}
\RequirePackage{luacode,luatextra}
\RequirePackage[fleqn]{mathtools,stmaryrd}
\RequirePackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
\RequirePackage{pdflscape}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
%
\RequirePackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{ et~}
\newcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{ et~}
\newcommand{\crefmiddleconjunction}{, }
\RequirePackage{totcount}
%
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF}{mmm}
    {
     \IfNoValueTF{#1}
      {#2} % true
      {\tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} {#2} {#3}} % false
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%
\RequirePackage{xargs}
\RequirePackage{centernot,cancel}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox,refcount}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table,x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{monbleu}{HTML}{003366}
%
%Encadrement
\RequirePackage[skins,breakable,xparse,many]{tcolorbox}
%--------------
%Définition/Théorème/etc.
%
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tcolorbox}{\savenotes}
\AfterEndEnvironment{tcolorbox}{\spewnotes}
%
\newcommand*\ifcounter[1]{%
  \ifcsname c@#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
%
\NewDocumentCommand\DefinirTheoreme{m m m m m m}{%
    \DeclareTColorBox[auto counter,
        number within       = chapter,
        crefname            = {#5}{#6}]{#1}{ O{} O{} }
    {
        enhanced ,
        coltitle            = #3    ,
        colframe            = #4    ,
        colbacktitle        = white ,
        boxrule             = 0.5pt ,
        toprule at break    = 0mm   ,
        bottomrule at break = 0mm   ,
        breakable                   ,
        attach boxed title to top left={xshift=3mm, yshift=-3mm, yshifttext=-1mm},
        IfEmptyTF={##1}%
          {title=#2 \thetcbcounter}%
          {title=#2 \thetcbcounter {~|~}{\color{black}\normalfont\bfseries ##1}},
        ##2,
    }%
}
\DefinirTheoreme{defi}{Définition}{monbleu}{monbleu}{Définition}{Définitions}

%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{defi}[][label={croiss}]
Soit \((x,y)\in \left(\mathbb{R}_+\right)^2\) tel que \(x<y\) (resp. \(x\leqslant y)\), alors 
\[ x^2 < y^2 \;\; (\text{resp. }x^2 \leqslant y^2 ),  \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{y}.\]
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}
Soit \((x,y)\in \left(\mathbb{R}_+\right)^2\) tel que \(x<y\) (resp. \(x\leqslant y)\), alors 
\[ x^2 < y^2 \;\; (\text{resp. }x^2 \leqslant y^2 ),  \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{y}.\]
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}[non-empty]
Soit \((x,y)\in \left(\mathbb{R}_+\right)^2\) tel que \(x<y\) (resp. \(x\leqslant y)\), alors 
\[ x^2 < y^2 \;\; (\text{resp. }x^2 \leqslant y^2 ),  \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{y}.\]
\end{defi}
\end{document}
```

[image]